# return rows of sql query with MAX(date) and GROUP BY id

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
id      position      date
1          a          2012 01 12
2          a          2012 01 22
3          a          2012 01 22
1          b          2012 02 13
1          c          2012 02 22
2          b          2012 01 23
```

How can i get the row of records with MAX(date) that group by id

```
id      position      date
1          c          2012 01 22
2          b          2012 01 23
3          a          2012 01 22
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Note that your expected output has a typo.  `2012-01-23` is not the latest date for position `b`.  It should be `2012-02-13` instead.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i got mysql here. i tried the max(date) with delivered table but im kinda lost  after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.position, r.Maxdate
FROM (
      SELECT id, MAX(date) as Maxdate
      FROM Yourtable
      GROUP BY id
) r
INNER JOIN Yourtable t
ON t.id = r.id AND t.date = r.Maxdate
```

Comment: we have the same delivered table but I'm kinda lost after the alias of delivered query. > i got unknown column a in field list

Comment: this assumes the `Maxdate` value is unique. if there are two rows with the same date which is the max for the group, it's not guaranteed that the join will get the id that belongs to the row that the subquery considered max. Then again either of the rows are valid for this logic so it shouldn't matter i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
select your_table.* from your_table  
inner join 
(select max(date) as maxdt, id from your_table  group by id) t
on your_table.id = t.id and your_table.date  = t.maxdt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done using window functions:

```
select id, position, "date"
from (
  select id, position, "date", max("date") over (partition by id) as max_date
  from the_table
) t
where "date" = max_date
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    table1.id, 
    table1.name,
    table1.dob
FROM users_report as table1
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(dob) AS dob, id
  FROM users_report 
  GROUP BY user_id) AS table2
  ON table1.id= table2.id 
ORDER BY table1.id ASC;
```

Comment: Would be helpful add context with your answer in the future.

Answer (score -2):

I read the other answers but this also would work. I don't see why a second select is necessary.

```
SELECT id, my_position, Max(my_date)
FROM test.test
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: You have `my_position` in select list, which not uses aggregate function and also not in `group by` list.

Comment: It won't work in MSSQL

Comment: @OtoShavadze what if i also had a `MIN(my_date)` as well in the select list? which one would the `my_position` column belong to?